# How to apply aggregation stage based on the value of the field in mongodb?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have documents with the fields _id, and value.
The value field can have value as a string or integer value.

```
    {_id: 1, value: '13 hr 30mins'},
    {_id: 2, value: '25 hr'},
    {_id: 3, value: '45mins'},
    {_id: 4, value: '8hr 15 mins'},
```

I want to check if the value field is string and has 'hr' or 'mins' and if yes want to convert the string to value(int) in just hours or don't perform just pass all the documents to the next stage

```
Expected Output:
    {_id: 1, value: 13.5},
    {_id: 2, value: 25},
    {_id: 3, value: 0.75},
    {_id: 4, value: 8.25},
```

The problem I am facing is if the value field has no 'hr' or 'mins' terms in it should just skip the convertion.
Want to apply the aggregation stage on the criteria on the value the value field has in the document.

I tried doing

```
{
                            $project : {
                                value : 1
                            },
                            $match : {
                                value : {
                                    $cond :[
                                        {value : {$in : [/hr/i, /mins/i] }},
                                        {
                                                $set: {
                                                  value: {
                                                    $regexFind: {
                                                      input: "$value",
                                                      regex: "(?:(\\d+) hr){0,1}\\s*(?:(\\d+) mins){0,1}"
                                                    }
                                                  }
                                                }
                                              },
                                              {
                                                $set: {
                                                  value: {
                                                    $round: [
                                                      {
                                                        $sum: [
                                                          {
                                                            $toInt: {
                                                              $arrayElemAt: [
                                                                "$value.captures",
                                                                0
                                                              ]
                                                            }
                                                          },
                                                          {
                                                            $divide: [
                                                              {
                                                                $toInt: {
                                                                  $arrayElemAt: [
                                                                    "$value.captures",
                                                                    1
                                                                  ]
                                                                }
                                                              },
                                                              60
                                                            ]
                                                          }
                                                        ]
                                                      },
                                                      2
                                                    ]
                                                  }
                                                }
                                              }
                                                
                                        {}
                                    ]
                                }
                            }
                        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. `$set` - Create `regexValue` field with below regex:

```
^(?:(\d+)\s{0,1}hr){0,1}\s*(?:(\d+)\s{0,1}mins){0,1}$
```

`^` - Start with

`(?:)` - Non-capturing group

`(\d+)` - Capturing group with one or more digits

`\s{0,1}` - With zero or one space only

`(?:(\d+)\s{0,1}hr){0,1}` - With zero or one `hr` non-capturing group

`\s*` - Zero or many spaces

`(?:(\d+)\s{0,1}mins){0,1}` - With zero or one `mins` non-capturing group

`$` - Ends of

2. `$set` - Set `value` field.

   2.1. `$cond` - Check `regexValue` is null.

   2.1.1. If true, then perform data extraction and transformation.

   2.1.2. If false, remain the `value` field.
3. `$unset` - Remove `regexValue` field.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $set: {
      regexValue: {
        $regexFind: {
          input: "$value",
          regex: "^(?:(\\d+)\\s{0,1}hr){0,1}\\s*(?:(\\d+)\\s{0,1}mins){0,1}$"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $set: {
      value: {
        "$cond": {
          if: {
            $ne: [
              "$regexValue",
              null
            ]
          },
          then: {
            $round: [
              {
                $sum: [
                  {
                    $toInt: {
                      $arrayElemAt: [
                        "$regexValue.captures",
                        0
                      ]
                    }
                  },
                  {
                    $divide: [
                      {
                        $toInt: {
                          $arrayElemAt: [
                            "$regexValue.captures",
                            1
                          ]
                        }
                      },
                      60
                    ]
                  }
                ]
              },
              2
            ]
          },
          else: "$value"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $unset: "regexValue"
  }
])
```

[Sample Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/-QbBFocwUV_)